# Setting up virtual hosts on El Capitan

Tags: macos, apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf, osx-elcapitan

What I've done is:

Added this to httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/site1"
    ServerName site1.loc
    ServerAlias www.site1.loc
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/site2"
    ServerName site2.loc
    ServerAlias www.site2.loc
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/
</VirtualHost>
```

And in hosts file, I added this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
127.0.0.1 site1.localhost
127.0.0.1 site2.localhost
```

And finally in httpd.conf I uncommented this line:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

I have restarted apache after this and after I have tried to run something like this:

```
http://site1/index.html
```

or `http://site2` I get an error which saying:

> This site can’t be reached

I am missing something very obvious? It was a long time I did this on Windows, so I guess I made some silly mistake. Also I get :

> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

when I try to reach localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it worked after I have changed these:

```
127.0.0.1 site1.localhost
127.0.0.1 site2.localhost
```

to this:

```
127.0.0.1 site1.loc
127.0.0.1 site2.loc
```